unnecessary axis over all subplots numbered from 0 to 1
I came up with this strange axis around all subplots I've plotted, which is numbered from 0 to 1.
I tried simplifying the code e.g. removing plotting through the for loop etc., but it still plots.
Any suggestions or ideas about it? Thanks.
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(ncols*4,nrows*4))
#plt.subplots_adjust(wspace=0.0001,hspace=0.2)
plt.suptitle('Profiles \n run=%s'%(run), fontsize=10)

ibeg=1 ; iend=len(dtimes)+1
for i,idt in zip(range(ibeg,iend),range(0,len(dtimes))):
    
    ax=plt.subplot(nrows, ncols,i)
    
    dtime=dtimes[idt]
   
    df=pd.read_excel('plots/%s/model_temp_profiles.xlsx'%run, sheet_name=dtime)

    line1=ax.plot(df['TEMPERATURE'],df['depth'], color='black', linewidth=2, label='Temp. model')
    lines=line1
    [![enter image description here][1]][1]            
    ax.set_xlim(min_temp,max_temp)
    ax.set_ylim(-0.1,max_depth)

    #-adjust y and x labels and ticks
    if i==ibeg or i in [5,9,13,17,21]: #- first column subplots
        ax.set_ylabel('depth (m)', fontsize=9)
    else: #-other subplots
        ax.tick_params(left=False, labelleft=False)

    ax.set_xlabel('degC', fontsize=9)

    #ax.set_yticks(np.arange(min(depths), max(depths), 5.0))
    ax.set_xticks(np.arange(0, max_temp, 5.0))

    #- prepare legend              
    labs=[l.get_label() for l in lines]
    ax.legend(lines, labs, loc=4, frameon=True, fontsize=10)

    ax.grid(color='grey',linestyle=':', linewidth=0.2)

    ax.set_title('Temp.\n%s' %dtime, x=x_title, y=y_title, fontsize=10,\
                bbox=dict(facecolor='white', alpha=0.5, edgecolor='none'))

    ax.invert_yaxis()

plt.savefig('plots/%s/profiles.png' %(run), dpi=600)


You created that axes on your first line when you called subplots.  I think you want to use plt.figure there instead.

Yes, it was the point, and now it works fine. Thanks!
